# Does this applet work for you?

Tags: java, internet-explorer-6, applet, cross-browser

I have found a solution to get the full file path of a file that is about to be uploaded using a Java Applet. I need this for an internal system not anything else "dodgy"!

Can anyone confirm if this works in an IE6 browser: **http://www.maschek.hu/preview/ffx3_file/filepath.html**

I have an IETester application that has IE6/7/8 in one place and all IE6 does is just load/wait for the page and it has been 10 minutes. I am trying to determine if this applet will work in IE6?

Its using PARAM tags so is that a no? This has worked on my IE8.

To get this to work, do I need to do more than change the PARAM tags to Object tags?

Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this website -->
**http://www.spoon.net/browsers/**

Its a browser Sandbox. You can run any browser from the web. Very useful stuff.

Comment: Thanks, this looks more reliable than what I am using. I find that the applet is initialized which is a good thing but any function calls made to it, crashes IE6 and closes the browser! I need to open a new question I think as I have no idea why that happens, there isn't even any log files I can look at!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your application in IE6 you could use the [Internet Explorer Application Compatibility Virtual PC Images](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en) supplied free by Microsoft.  This will probably be more reliable than asking other people to do it for you.

Comment: I was hoping someone would try it out and then help me answer questions further down.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted - it's a good and free way to have a set test environment.