# Why does this Java applet crash and close IE6?

Tags: java, javascript, internet-explorer-6, applet, cross-browser

I am using the following Java Applet to get the full file path of a file that is to be uploaded: [**SVN LittleShoot**](http://svn.littleshoot.org/svn/littleshoot/trunk/client/applet/src/main/java/LittleShootApplet.java).

The thing is, the applet is initialized and it seems to be running in IE6 - but when I call one of the functions from JavaScript to the applet to open the file dialog box the browser crashes and closes itself just the dialog because shows up.

Why is the case? How can I debug this, I don't have any log files to look at? What may be the cause - I am willing to take wild guesses here as I am desperate!

HTML Usage (removed JS):

```
<OBJECT classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93" id="LittleShootApplet" name="LittleShootApplet" width="0" height="0">  
<PARAM name="code" value="LittleShootApplet" />
<PARAM name="scriptable" value="true" />
<PARAM name="mayscript" value="true" />
<PARAM name="style" value="xdisplay: none; width:0; height:0; padding:0; margin:0;" />
</OBJECT>
```

### Update

I get this error now: "Object doesn't support this property or method." I think its talking about this line.

```
<input type="button" value="Browse.." onclick="document.LittleShootApplet.openDialog('onFileDialogFile', 'onFileDialogCancel');">
```

Using just the HTML version, I get a JS error!

Comment: Does the applet work with Firefox? If yes: what are the versions of the java-plugins?

Comment: Yes, it works with Firefox and even IE8. My JRE (SE) version is 1.6 which I guess is the same for the java-plugins as it comes bundled with the JRE.

Comment: @Pointy - what do you mean the JavaScript tag? Do you mean why am I using JS to call the applet?? I need to use it in this way.

Comment: Does it show the dialog and crashes afterwards or does it crash before you can see the dialog?

Comment: I open the dialog from with IE and then all it shows is the initialization of the applet and it then crashes.

Comment: Have you tried surrounding the line

openDialog("onFileDialogFile", "onFileDialogCancel");

in newFileDialog with a try {} catch (Exception e) {e.printStrackTrace()} to catch all Exceptions?

Comment: I haven't tried that, but I think this is more of an IE6 issue and was wondering if my usage of this class was not set-up properly for IE6, because it works on all other browsers on windows XP (except IE7 haven't got that). I have added my usage.

Comment: Is this continuing from your earlier post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906999/does-this-applet-work-for-you

Comment: Not really, I found what was happening thanks to Matt Joslin. My browser wasn't doing anything (not even loading the applet) but Matt's solution showed the browser was actually crashing.

Comment: I am using this particular script as well and also have problems with it.
Did you by any chance need to sign the applet? Thanks

Comment: I gave up with it to be honest, I need something that works with IE in a safe way, so I have opted for a less effective user interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if you put in some test calls from within the Applet itself: to make the same call that the JS calls hook into ? Does this also crash ?

If it doesn't crash, then I would say you have found a bug in the browser itself (or 'LiveConnect' - whatever the kids are calling Java<->JS communication these days..)

If that it is the case, I would suggest the following:

1. Simplify the Applet, so that it contains the minimum amount of code in order that it crashes: same goes for the JSScript.
2. Get it to crash - then your stuck with debugging a Windows program I think:

http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/Debugging/default.mspx

Answer (score 1):

Open the Java Console and load the applet.  Go to the Control Panel > Java > advanced and enable debugging and the console

Comment: Those are enabled, but when I view the Java console within the browser and it crashes, it takes that console along with it. Is there a global standalone console I can use??

Comment: I think if the browser dies the window will close too but you can still view the logs/trace files under your Applicaiton Data/Sun/Java directory

Answer (score 0):

You seem to say that just opening up the Java Console causes a crash as well ?

If that is the case , see this posting on the Sun Web Site:

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6563344